How can I check if an array of numbers is an incremental sequence with no jumps?
I am trying to validate if an array of numbers is an incremental sequence with no jumps between numbers. For example:
const items = [1,2,3,4] // Should return true
const items = [1,2,4] // Should return false - jumps from 2 to 4
const items = [5,6,7] // Should return true

The array doesn't always starts at 1, like the above example which returns true that starts at 5. How could I write a function to validate this so that it returns true or false depending on if the sequence has jumps?
Thanks in advance.

You forgot to post your attempt to solve this problem.

Loop through the array, checking if each element is 1+ the previous element.

How to ask homework question and Open letter to students with homework problems

Adding to what @Barmar recommends, iterate the list and maintain a reference to the prior item to compare the current one to.

This question is similar to: How to check if an array is increasing in javascript?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Also, this question, which is a closer dupe than the one above.

the question was closed before I could post my answer.. by the way another interesting approach was making a Set out of the input array (to rule out duplicates) and (after sorting in case the corresponding flag was passed as true to the function) just check if the last item minus the first item of the array made the array's current length

@DiegoD - you can add your answer to an existing question like this one

@devlincarnate yes you are right.. posted there indeed. Later deleted because I should really have better checked edge cases.. never mind.. it was a virtuoso attempt that was not worth showing off

function isIncrementalSequence(arr) {
  if (arr.length <= 1) return true; // Single element or empty array is considered a sequence

  for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] !== arr[i - 1] + 1) {
      return false; // If there's a jump, return false
    }
  }

  return true; // No jumps found, return true
}

// Test cases
console.log(isIncrementalSequence([1, 2, 3, 4])); // true
console.log(isIncrementalSequence([1, 2, 4]));    // false
console.log(isIncrementalSequence([5, 6, 7]));    // true


Checking if each member (excluding the first one) minus the previous one is equal to 1 should work out for you.
const items = [1,2,3,4] // Should return true
//2 - 1 = 1, 3 - 2 = 1,...
const items = [1,2,4] // Should return false
//4 - 2 = 2 -> false
const items = [5,6,7] // Should return true
// 6 - 5 = 1,...


You can write a function that loops over the array and compares the current item in the array to the previous item. If the response is not equal to one, break the function and return false.
See function below:
const isArrayIsInSequence = (items: number[]) => {
  if (items.length <= 1) return true;

  for (let i = 1; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i] - items[i - 1] !== 1) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}

